# Finding Number Of Derangement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$$n!=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni(!(n-i))$$
Hi. I am trying to review Discrete Math 1 for the new term. I couldn't find a proper strategy to prove this statement. What would be the best way to prove such a question using equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of arrangements of $(1,\dots,n)$ such that exactly $i$ elements are not moved equals $$\binom{n}{i}(!(n-i))$$

A summation of these terms gives all $n!$ arrangements.